# Jquery Mobile swipe events in Android 4.2.2 not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have written a mobile web application that uses the JQuery mobile swipeleft and swiperight events but these are not working on a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.2.2.  Running the web application in either the standard web browser or in Chrome has the same issue: the swipe events are not detected.

The following is how I am trying to detect the events which works fine in other devices I have tested it on, even Android devices (but not Android 4.2.2):

```
$('#showImage').on("swipeleft", function (event) {
if (currentScale != initialScale) return;
if (currentPage < maxPage) {
  ++currentPage;
  img.src = document.getElementById("page" + zeroPad(currentPage, 2) + "url").value;
}
});

$('#showImage').on("swiperight", function (event) {
if (currentScale != initialScale) return;
if (currentPage > 1) {
  --currentPage;
  img.src = document.getElementById("page" + zeroPad(currentPage, 2) + "url").value;
}
});
```

Is there anything I can do, code-wise, to capture these events in Android 4.2.2?

Comment: Have you able to find a solution to this?,I'm facing the same issue

Comment: No I have not.  In addition to this issue, trying to capture tap events is failing in Android 4.2.2.  Both the swipe and tap work fine in Android 4.0.4.

Comment: I had a same issue, Button click event did not work in 4.2.2, I used <a> tags to buttons,I changed the tags to <button>.After that vents worked perfectly on all versions.Check your html tags.May you could find solution. good luck

Comment: In my case I am trying to apply the jquery mobile events to an HTML5 canvas element.  Do you know of a way that your button solution could be applicable to that situation?  I really consider this a failing of the Android 4.2.2 OS but I am willing to look at any work-around that will fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are having two problems here.

First is caused by a bug in JQM that has been resolved but is not yet implemented https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5534

Basically the min distance measured by the swipe event must take into account the pixel density of the device. So in JQM's case, the following change to touch.js will solve the issue:

```
horizontalDistanceThreshold = window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ? 15 : 30;
verticalDistanceThreshold = window.devicePixelRatio >= 2 ? 15 : 30;
```

The second is todo with kitkat firing a touchcancel instead of a touchend. The solution is to delegate touchcancel to touchend.